# What is the difference between Axon terminal and Synapses

Tags: brain, neurology, nervous-system

I've read from a book that

> axon terminals make connections on target cells.

I understand it. but at another line they said that

> Neuron-to-neuron connections are made onto the dendrites and cell bodies of other neurons. These connections, known as synapses.

Now I do not understand that if axon terminals make connection with target cells or dendrites make connection with target cells? 
Please help me to understand this!
Thanks..

Comment: What book are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If you have a look at one of the most famous reference book in neuroscience "Principles of neural science" by Kandel (Fifth Edition), on page 22:*

There is this figure:

[image]

And here is the description of the figure (extracts):

> Most neurons in the vertebrate nervous system have several main
>   features in common. The cell body contains the nucleus, the storehouse
>   of genetic information, and gives rise to two types of cell processes:
>   axons and dendrites. Axons are the transmitting element of neurons;
>   they vary greatly in length, some extending more than 2 m within the
>   body (...) **The action potential, the cell’s conducting signal, is
>   initiated at the initial segment of the axon and propagates to the
>   synapse, the site at which signals flow from one neuron to another**.
>   Branches of the axon of the presynaptic neuron transmit signals to the
>   postsynaptic cell. The branches of a single axon may form synapses
>   with as many as 1,000 postsynaptic neurons. **The apical and basal
>   dendrites together with the cell body are the input elements of the
>   neuron, receiving signals from other neurons**.

So axons connect with target neuronal cells, either on the dendrites or the soma, to propagate the action potential.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the synapse is made of:

- the presynaptic ending (membrane, terminal): which is actually the axon terminal and here is where we find the neurotransmitters.
- the postsynaptic ending (membrane, terminal): which could be a dendrite, an axon or a cell body, and here we find receptors for those neurotransmitters released from the axon terminal.

Between the two membranes there is a gap or space called synaptic cleft.
I hope this is clear for you.